# Como pegar o código html através de uma url no android studio

Tags: java, android, url

Gostaria de fazer como eu pego um código html de um site usando o android studio. Esse é o código que eu fiz, mas ele não returna nada.

```
private static String pegarURL(String a) {
    StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder();

    try {
        URL url = new URL(a);

        URLConnection urlConnection = url.openConnection();

        BufferedReader bufferedReader =
                new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(urlConnection.getInputStream()));

        String line;

        while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
            b.append(line + "\n");
        }

        bufferedReader.close();
    } catch(Exception e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return b.toString();

}

String h = pegarURL("https://www.google.com/");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A forma mais pratica que eu achei de fazer isso é a seguinte. Adicione nas dependências do seu gradle o código abaixo:

```
implementation 'com.koushikdutta.ion:ion:2.1.8'
```

De sync, depois importe as duas bibliotecas abaixo

```
import com.koushikdutta.async.future.FutureCallback;
import com.koushikdutta.ion.Ion;
```

E use o seguinte código para obter seu código HTML

```
Ion.with(getApplicationContext()).load("http://www.google.com").asString().setCallback(new FutureCallback<String>() { 
            @Override
            public void onCompleted(Exception e, String result) {
                Log.i("RESULTADO",result); // Aqui você trabalha com a resposta
            }
        });
```

Comment: Valeu, usei diversas formas, mas nenhuma funcionava. Essa me serviu bem. Obrigado!

Comment: De nada! Eu também já tinha procurado varias, encontrei algumas que funcionava, mas tinha que usar muito mais códigos.